# React Update a list with New Items But Ids might repeat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a stateful component which maintains `2 lists of different types`. As an example, think in terms of `cars`. Each car has a `make`(and lets say it has unique `makeId`) and `model`(again with a unique `modelId`).  Now my component first displays a list of makes, each having a `key` attribute whose value is `makeId`. Now upon click on a `make`, My `stateful` component updates the list with all the `models`(each having `modelId` as  `key` attribute) of the selected `make`. Now it might happen that some `make` had the same numeric value of `makeId` as  the numeric value of `modelId` now being rendered.(because makes and models go in different Relational tables). Will react face some issues while updating the list in this case?

**Example:**

> Below is the comparison of old and new list.

```html
<ul>
  <li key=1> Some Make X</li>
  <li key=2> Some Make Y</li>
</ul>


<ul>
  <li key=34> Some Model X</li>
  <li key=2> Some Model Y</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

React identifies elements with unique `key` prop. In a Component, if you think the list of elements will have overlapping ids you can always pass a unique `key` prop.

If the element you are rendering is relevant to make, pass in the key as

```
<div key={`make_${makeId}`} />
```

If the element you are rendering is relevant to model, pass in the key as

```
<div key={`model_${modelId}`} />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now it might happen that some make had the same numeric value of
>   `makeId` as the numeric value of `modelId` now being rendered.

From the question, it seems safe to assume that `makes` and `models` are two different arrays being rendered in different enclosures. Using these variables `modelId` and `makeId` as ID attributes in HTML, would need you to prepend a string to it, such as `model-${modelId}` or `make-${makeId}` because they have to be unique across the page.

However incase of React Keys, they have do not have to be global across the page, but only inside an Array to distinguish their siblings. So you can safely use `modelId` and `makeId` as keys without any modification.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings):

> Keys used within arrays should be unique among their siblings. However
>   they don’t need to be globally unique.

Comment: If you go by what is mentioned in [Detailed Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children), I think there will be a problem when the react will compare the previous VDom

Comment: The [Detailed doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) that you are referring to also has this exact line of keys needing to be unique only among siblings and not globally

Comment: Now suppose, after some action, we get the list  with keys 2019,2020 and 2015. but the value for the key 2015 has changed. Instead of duke, it is now blake. will react still update the list

Comment: @Manya Sure, if a key changes, you can trust React to update. But why would you change the key of an item? They are the ones that should not change. Or did you mean the value inside the list?

Comment: I have edited the question with an example. Can you take a look at it once.

Comment: @Manya I don't see any issues with this case, did you actually try and run across an issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184579/discussion-between-manya-and-boy-with-silver-wings).

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys `Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed`. It means that key will be used when your previous and new components are the same Component class and have the same props. As you list item components are completely changed (from model to make and vice versa), they will be re-rendered always. So there will be no render issue in this case